# How to combine laravel and vue routes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a simple laravel and vuejs CRUD Application. Vue Routes are not working, I am pretty new to vuejs; please see the code
Below is the code for web.php

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    });

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/vue','Api\PostController@home');
    Route::resource('/api','Api\PostController');
```

Following is the code for app.js

```
    require('./bootstrap');

    window.Vue = require('vue');

    window.VueRouter=require('vue-router').default;

    window.VueAxios=require('vue-axios').default;

    window.Axios=require('axios').default;

    let AppLayout = require('./components/App.vue');
    const Posts = Vue.component('Posts',require('./components/Posts.vue'));
    const EditPost = 
    Vue.component('EditPost',require('./components/EditPost.vue'));
    const AddPost = 
    Vue.component('AddPost',require('./components/AddPost.vue'));
    const DeletePost = 
    Vue.component('DeletePost',require('./components/AddPost.vue'));
    const ViewPosts = 
    Vue.component('ViewPosts',require('./components/ViewPosts.vue'));
    const ExampleComponent = 
   Vue.component('ViewPosts',require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

   // Registering routes
   Vue.use(VueRouter,VueAxios,axios);

   const routes = [
   {
    name: 'Posts',
    path: '/posts',
    component: Posts
   },
   {
    name: 'AddPost',
    path: '/add-posts',
    component: AddPost
   },
   {
    name: 'EditPost',
    path: '/edit-post/:id',
    component: EditPost
   },
   {
    name: 'DeletePost',
    path: '/delete-post',
    component: DeletePost
   },
   {
    name: 'ViewPosts',
    path: '/view-post',
    component: ViewPosts
   },
   {
    name: 'ExampleComponent',
    path: '/example-component',
    component: ExampleComponent
   },
 ];
    const router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes: routes});
    new Vue(
      Vue.util.extend(
      { router },
      AppLayout
     )).$mount('#app');
```

This is the code of my blade tamplate, when I browse http://localhost:8000/vue this view is being rendered. As you can see in the web.php code above.
I can also see the notification in console **You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
<!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
   <header class="page-header">
    <div class="branding">
        <img src="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Home page" class="logo"/>
        <h1>Vue.js CRUD With Laravel 5 application</h1>
    </div>
   </header>
 </div>
<section id="app">

</section>
<script>
  window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
    'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
]); ?>
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But when I run my application using

```
    php artisan serve
```

and browse to

```
    http://localhost:8000/posts
```

Application show a 404 error. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: in which blade file you have used the app.js for vuejs?

Comment: I am using it in vue_app.blade.php

Comment: I have answered a solution for you. Kindly let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a laravel route for the view where you are using the app.js (vuejs) in `routes/web.php` file.

```
Route::get('/route-name/?{name}', function(){
    return redirect('vue_app');
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

and then you have to use the laravel route as a parent route for the vuejs's routes and use the url like below,

```
http://localhost:8000/laravel-route/view-route
```

in your case,

```
http://localhost:8000/route-name/posts
```

Or you can also use,

```
Route::get('{any}', function () { 
    return view('vue_app'); 
})->where('any', '.*');
```

and instead of previous use `localhost:8000/posts`

Comment: Dear I am getting the same error, http://localhost:8000/route-name/posts do I need to change the app.js? let me edit question to include vue_app.blade.php

Comment: can you try, 
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view(''vue_app');
})->where('any', '.*');

instead of previous route and use http://localhost:8000/posts url directly?

Can you show your routes.php and error page?

Comment: It is working and redirecting to the required blade; there is no error, but I have confusion as you can see in my app.js I have written if the request is for /post, it has to render Posts component i.e Posts.vue, which is not being rendered. Can you figure out the issue?

Comment: Brother, I have given a solution of your second problem in an another answer below. Please check it. And It will be better if you ask two questions in separate post and also should accept this answer if it works for your initial problem. Then it will be beneficial for other who may face the similar scenario. Thank u

Answer (score 3):

Try this to your web.php route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/{catchall?}', function () {
    return response()->view('index');
})->where('catchall', '(.*)');
```

Answer (score 2):

if with {any} did not work, you may also try adding **?**

```
Route::get('/any-your-route/{any?}', function() {
  return view('your-view');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

hope this help you. i just try this code and work on laravel blade template with vue router.
Tested on **Laravel 8**

Answer (score 1):

For your **second part of question**,
You should use `<div>` instead of `<section>` and you have to bring the main/registered component inside of the html element selected by `id="app"` in blade file. in your case,

```
<div id="app">
   <app-layout></app-layout>
</div>
```

Hope this help you. you can check this [basic vuejs with laravel](https://medium.com/@mscherrenberg/laravel-5-6-vue-js-simple-form-submission-using-components-92b6d5fd4434)

PS: You should ask two different problem in two seperate posts.

Answer (score 0):

you can do simply like this.

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function(){
return view('welcome');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```