# How to integrate vue router into an existing laravel-vue project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have a laravel vue project and am struggling to install vue router.
I installed vue-cli via :
`npm install --save-dev @vue/cli-service`
then:

```
vue add router
```

the latter has created a whole bunch of starter files on a src folder (views, main.js, App.vue, router.js etc). I have all the frontend inside a resources folder which has the mixin, bootstrap and the laravel view folder. I've tried changing the imports and webpack mixins but had no success.
Anyone know how I can change the vue router plugin to my resources js folder / or change my webpack mixin into the src folder??

Solution:
Considering you have vue-cli and you want to add vue-router to your laravel-vue project (laravel 8+ and vue js3), ignore the commands I've mentioned above and instead you should add:

```
npm install vue-router@4
```

Then in app.js:

```
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router'


// Add routes here:
const routes = [
    {
    path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home'
    },
  ]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

I tried to add this into a separate router folder and then import it but wouldn't work so I'll just keep it in the same file. Hope this is helpful to anyone. Then you'll need to add the router-links and router-view but the vue-router documentation is quite good on those instructions, only not great for the configuration into laravel-vue projects (at least from what I've found)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, you need to declare routes in Laravel
When the user enter those routes, Laravel will look and serve the declared matching routes with Vue application

This is a duplicated question of this:
[How to combine laravel and vue routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434534/how-to-combine-laravel-and-vue-routes)

Comment: not quite, I was asking regarding vue-router, the package for SPA links. I actually figured it out and will leave here the solution in case anyone is facing the same despair I just did

Comment: what is the solution/?